# grumphp + php-cs-fixer + git : how to configure

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed php-cs-fixer and grumphp in my PHP project. My composer is :

```
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.16",
    "laravel/dusk": "^5.5",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpro/grumphp": "^0.17.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
},
```

When I try a commit, I have these messages :

```
GrumPHP detected a pre-commit command.

GrumPHP is sniffing your code!

Running task 1/1: PhpCsFixerV2... ✘

In ConfigurationResolver.php line 582:
[PhpCsFixer\ConfigurationException\InvalidConfigurationException (16)]
For multiple paths config parameter is required.
```

And when I try : vendor/bin/grumphp run, I have this error :

```
Loaded config default.
Using cache file ".php_cs.cache".

In Finder.php line 622:

[LogicException]
You must call one of in() or append() methods before iterating
over a Finder
```

I suppose that these two errors are linked.

My grumphp.yml is very basic (perhaps it is the problem...) :

```
parameters:
tasks:
    phpcsfixer2: ~
```

What had I forgotten somewhere?

Comment: Try using phpcsfixer and not phpcsfixer2

Comment: Checkout https://adapttive.com/blog/grumphp-in-magento-2